# Any reCAPTCHA equivalent security for Chat?

Tags: servicecloud, chat, recaptcha

We need to secure web-chat against bot attacks on our website. Although reCAPTCHA sounds the right solution for this, Salesforce does not have this feature for Chat.

Is there any other similar solution to secure Chat in Salesforce?

We would not have a pre-chat form, as the contextual data would directly be passed from website to the Chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your chat is public the only way in which you can prevent this is by having a prechat form with a reCaptcha or a honeypot. If your chat is being a portal with authenticated users then you don't have much to worry about but I guess this is not your case.